# Can I customise the 'Exit' menu in Big Picture mode?

Tags: steam

I am in the process of building myself a Steam Box - a PC running Steam that is going to be plugged into my TV without a keyboard and mouse plugged into it. I am looking at running Steam instead of Explorer as the shell, on account of Windows 8 forcibly starting up with Metro and me not wanting to install a workaround to prevent Metro from appearing.

With this in mind, I was wondering if I could customise the contents of the 'Exit' menu in Steam Big Picture Mode. The default Exit menu contains the following options;

[image]

Ideally, I'd want to get rid of the following options;

- Return to Desktop
- Exit Steam
- Change User...

Is this possible? How can I customise the 'Exit' menu in Steam Big Picture mode?

Comment: The layout file for this part of Big Picture mode seems to be Steam\tenfoot\resource\layout\quit.xml (and a stylesheet at Steam\tenfoot\resource\styles\quit.css), but Steam generally doesn't allow modifying the core layout files (they get replaced either at launch, or at the very least on updates). Skins might work, but I don't think Big Picture mode *has* proper skin support... so the only option would be modifying the original files. It might require the files to be changed after starting Steam, but before starting Big Picture mode - if that doesn't work, I strongly doubt that it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, but as of the recent Steam releases you can trick Steam into believing it is running under SteamOS by launching Steam with the `-steamos` command line parameter.

Once in big picture mode, this option removes the 'Return to Desktop' option and 'Exit Steam' option from the Exit menu.

Comment: what is the minimum required version for this to work?

Comment: @kalina: I thought I was opted in to the beta on this laptop but I'm not, so beta is not required.  Do you need more precise information?

Comment: @kalina: Your edit says "once in big picture mode".  You can start there with `-bigpicture` or change your interface preferences.

Comment: You can, but just starting with `-steamos` without `-bigpicture` or changing your preferences will load up the default Steam interface - you can edit that in if you want but I've already accepted your answer.

Comment: Alt-f4 can be used to get out of big picture, if need be

Comment: You can also toggle between modes with ALT+Enter